# php files worked perfectly on localhost but not on the webserver

Tags: php, webserver, localhost

Good day everyone, I have been battling with an issue for quite some months now. I have a php program that work perfectly on the localhost but one of the php files refuses to work on the webserver .ie. on my website after uploading. All other php files worked but the register.php  files refuses to work on the webserver. what might likely be the cause. I am doing anything wrong. Kindly assit.

```
 // register.php code





<?php
        include('header.php'); 
        include('navbar_teacher.php');
        include 'core/init.php';




        logged_in_redirect();


        if (empty($_POST) === false) {

            $required_fields = array('username ','password','password_again','first_name','class','mac','phone_no','email','js1','js2','address');
            foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
                if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) ===  true) { 
                $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
                break 1;
                }
                }
            if (empty($errors) === true) {
            if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username  \''. $_POST['username'].'\' is already taken.';
            }
            if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any space.';
            }
            if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6 ) {
                $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters.';
            }
            if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
                $errors[] = 'Your password do not match.';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)=== false) {
            $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required';
        }
        if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email  \''. $_POST['email'].'\' is already in use.';
        }
            }
        }
        ?> 

        <?php
        if (isset($_GET ['success'])=== true && empty($_GET['success'])=== true) {
            echo 'You\'ve been registered successfully! Please check your email to activate your account.';
        }else {
        if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            $register_data =array(
            'username'       => $_POST['username'],
            'password'       => $_POST['password'],
            'first_name'       => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name'        => $_POST['last_name'],
            'class'             => $_POST['class'],
            'mac'               => $_POST['mac'],
            'phone_no'              => $_POST['phone_no'],
            'email'            => $_POST['email'],

            'address'          => $_POST['address'],
            'email_code'       =>md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())  
        );
        register_user($register_data);
        //header('Location: register.php?success');
        echo("<script>location.href = 'register.php?success=$msg';</script>");
        exit();
        } else if (empty($errors) === false)  {
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }
        ?>
        <body id="class_div">



        <div class="span8" id="content">
                             <div class="row-fluid">
        <?php include('about.php'); ?>

        </div>
                </div>


         <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span4">
            <?php include 'add_register.php';?>                    <!-- block -->




        </body>
        </html>
        <?php 
        }

        include 'includes/overall/footer.php';?>
```

//init.php code

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    //error_reporting(0);

    require 'database/connect.php';
    require 'functions/general.php';
    require 'functions/users.php';

    $current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $current_file = end($current_file);



    if(logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id','username','password','first_name', 'last_name','class','mac','phone_no','email','address','email_code','active','password_recover','type','allow_email','profile');
    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        //header('Location: index.php');
        echo("<script>location.href = 'index.php=$msg';</script>");
        exit();
    }
    if ($current_file !== 'changepassword.php' && $user_data['password_recover']== 1) { 
        header('Location:  changepassword.php?force');
        exit();
    }
    } 
    //echo  $user_data['type'];
    $errors = array();

    ?>






    //users.php code



<?php

   function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $register_data['password'] =md5($register_data['password']);
    $fields =  '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data   =  '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\''; 

    $db->query(("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
    email($register_data['email'], 'Activate your account', "Hello "  .  $register_data ['first_name'] . ",\n\n You need to activate your account, so use the link below:\n\nhttp://ckischools.org/personal/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" .$register_data['email_code'] . "\n\n -ckischools ");

    }
```

All other php files worked perfectly well on the server except the register.php which has a link with init.php and users.php

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file or a web.conf file in the root where you are storing these php files.  Sometimes you can have issues with these if they are not properly set. Also make sure your server's php.ini file is set properly.

Comment: *but the register.php files refuses to work on the webserver.* explain what refuses to work means, are u getting any errors?

Comment: Look at the error log. It can tell a lot of thing.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the data at all, your current query will fail if a user enters a `'`-sign or ends an input with a backslash.

Comment: Don't use `md5()` for password hashing. It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5, you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Are you using the same technology for both? OS of local vs OS of server?

Comment: You also have an unmatched amount of `(` in your `$db->query((`-call. That should actually give you a real error, regardless which server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the cause - but I would change the include order to:

```
include('core/init.php'); 
include('navbar_teacher.php');
include('header.php');
```

as you have a session being started in `core/init.php` which must be started *before* any output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#refsect1-function.session-start-notes

---

You could add a further check by testing that the session was actually created:

```
$sessionStarted = session_start();

if($sessionStarted)
{
    // code here
}
else
{
    // echo('Could not start session!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your comment, I have tried some of the suggetsion made but it still not working i rearrange the code include('core/init.php'); 
include('navbar_teacher.php');
include('header.php');

Comment: but the register.php files refuses to work on the webserver.means that any user i add will not be inserted on my database. that is why i include the init.php file and the users,php file to my question

Comment: @oduswale I think, as mentioned in the question comments, that you need to elaborate on "refuses to work" - at the moment we don't know what that means. What is/isn't happening that makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: is `$db` set up as a global variable? I don't think it's in scope for your `register_user()` function

Comment: Macro man- Refuses to add data to the database after you have filled the form and click on submit the data will not be submitted if it on my webserver but it will  be submitted if it is on a local server

Comment: @oduswale then we need to see where you initialise the `$db` variable.

Comment: Macro Man i didnt use $db it was a mistake by me  while i was uploading to this comment group. i used   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)"); The problem still persist. thanks for all your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found solution to the problem,  thanks for all your contribution. I will alight where the problem was and the solution i profer which work perfectly.
The problem was in the registration form and also the submit form

// the initial form

```
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                 <ul>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>UserName*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="username">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Password*:</label>:Hint-  Minimum 6 characters<br>
<input  type="password" name="password">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Password Again*:</label>
<input  type="password" name="password_again">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>FirstName*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="first_name">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>LastName:</label>
<input  type="text" name="last_name" />
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Student's Class:</label>
<input  type="text" name="class" />
</div>

</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">

<label>Unique Address:</label>
<input  type="text" name="mac" />
</div>

</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">

<label>Phone Number:</label>
<input  type="text" name="phone_no" />
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Email*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="email">
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Contact Address:</label>
<textarea name="address"></textarea>
</div>
</li>
<input  type="submit" value="Register">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
                                        </div>
</form>
```

//the initial submit form

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET ['success'])=== true && empty($_GET['success'])=== true) {
    echo 'You\'ve been registered successfully! Please check your email to activate your account.';
}else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data =array(
    'username'       => $_POST['username'],
    'password'       => $_POST['password'],
    'first_name'       => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name'        => $_POST['last_name'],
    'class'             => $_POST['class'],
    'mac'               => $_POST['mac'],
    'phone_no'              => $_POST['phone_no'],
    'email'            => $_POST['email'],

    'address'          => $_POST['address'],
    'email_code'       =>md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())  
);
register_user($register_data);
//header('Location: register.php?success');
echo("<script>location.href = 'register.php?success=$msg';</script>");
exit();
} else if (empty($errors) === false)  {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

The problem was solved by adding 'email_code' to the form since on my table email_code was not defined to be 0 or 1.
'email_code'       =>md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())

```
solution
 <li>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label>RE-Type Email*:</label>
    <input  type="text" name="email_code">
    </div>
    </li>
```

// the initial form

```
                                <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                 <ul>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>UserName*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="username">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Password*:</label>:Hint-  Minimum 6 characters<br>
<input  type="password" name="password">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Password Again*:</label>
<input  type="password" name="password_again">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>FirstName*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="first_name">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>LastName:</label>
<input  type="text" name="last_name" />
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Student's Class:</label>
<input  type="text" name="class" />
</div>

</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">

<label>Unique Address:</label>
<input  type="text" name="mac" />
</div>

</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">

<label>Phone Number:</label>
<input  type="text" name="phone_no" />
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Email*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="email">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>RE-Type Email*:</label>
<input  type="text" name="email_code">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="control-group">
<label>Contact Address:</label>
<textarea name="address"></textarea>
</div>
</li>
<input  type="submit" value="Register">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
                                        </div>
</form>
```